# How to do Multiple File Upload in Spring - Java Config

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I been trying to find a example of how to do multiple file upload in Spring MVC **without using XML only Java Config**. So far have found nothing and a lot of people that just either want hits to sites or don't know what java configuration v xml configuration is.

I don't use Spring Boot and don't want to as I want to learn this framework no matter how difficult.

Even advice on how to convert the following line to java config would be appreciated:

```
<bean id="multipartResolver" class="org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver">
    <property name="maxUploadSize" value="1000000" />
</bean>
```

Please do advise also what JARs i would need for the above multipartResolver.

Thanks a bunch gang

Comment: does [this](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/01/spring-mvc-3-upload-multiple-files.html) and [this](http://crunchify.com/spring-mvc-tutorial-how-to-upload-multiple-files-to-specific-location/) help you

Comment: Both of those examples are XML config, please refer to the first line of my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That line translates to

```
@Bean
public MultipartResolver multipartResolver() {
    org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver multipartResolver = new org.springframework.web.multipart.commons.CommonsMultipartResolver();
    multipartResolver.setMaxUploadSize(1000000);
    return multipartResolver;
}
```

Within a `@Configuration` class which you'd load in your Servlet context.

You need [`commons-fileupload`](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-fileupload/) library for this to work.

Comment: Thanks Sotirios, i'll give it a go later on (code out of access atm) and see how it behaves. But looks about right.

Comment: unfortunately its not working. its constantly triggering my security and denying it access once i hit the submit button.

Comment: @aesir Then that's a security issue related to that config and to your mappings.

Comment: By looks of things its a bug with Spring Security.

Comment: @Aeseir I don't know enough about Spring Security to help you there. Consider asking a new question.